# Motorola USB Drivers on Windows 8

Tags: adb, windows, usb-drivers

Is there any way to install the Motorola USB drivers on Windows 8? I downloaded MotoHelper, but it won't install, saying that the OS Version is unknown. Is there some other way to get ADB to see my Droid X, or can I somehow extract the drivers from the installer?

I am not worried about stability - just playing around with the OS for now. Unfortunately, not being able to do Android development is making it less than fun.

Comment: You might want to check to see if [SU] has any posts on getting drivers to work in Windows 8.

Comment: Cross posted to [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/407903/getting-android-drivers-to-work-on-windows-8-community-preview). Thanks!

Comment: Oh, you might want to tweak that a little -- mobile device questions are off-topic there.  Just to make it clear that you want to get PC-side drivers working.  I'm not sure of the best way to do that since it seems there might not be a general solution.  Maybe something like asking how to trick the installer into thinking it's Windows 7, or something ... in the end it's up to you :P